# Should comments auto delete? (Podcast #400)

Tags: discussion, comments, podcast

In [podcast episode #400 (recast link to the section)](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/oral-history-of-stack-overflow-founders-WZcIZgGY?recast=aa42dcc5-ef83-51ed-a257-03552874fa96) Jeff Atwood brings up that he would have made comments transient.

I wanted to come and see what the discussion was around this idea, but I didn't find anything current on the topic. I personally like the idea, quoting Jeff again from the podcast:

> If your comment has value, then take it from the post-it note that's stuck at the bottom and move it into the question or move it into the answer by editing. That's what you're supposed to do.

Comment: How recent do you want? There's [quite a few questions already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204402?sort=newest) on this subject (follow the duplicate chains for more) on this topic, and I'm not sure what has changed since

Comment: Weird, I'm a new contributor here sure.. But I can't fathom why I didn't see anything related. Even the related question while I was authoring this didn't bring up anything I felt was relevant. Thanks for the link